# Puppeteer: Generate a PDF card 2.25in x 3.75in in 300DPI. Stuck with 144 DPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to generate a PDF of a card to be ready for printing. A card size is 2in x 3.5in but we leave a bleed on all the sides so our PDF is 2.25in x 3.75in.

Our application is written in Ruby on Rails and we use the "Grover" gem which is a wrapper around Google's Puppeteer. My code samples are not in straight NodeJS because of that.

I am using the latest versions of the gem and Puppeteer (19.6.0).

I have done multiple attempts to increase the DPI such as playing with the `viewport` size, `device_scale_factor`, the `scale`, specify in Puppeteer the `width` and `height` and also try to specify it by CSS using `@page { ... }`.

I only was successfull at generating the proper PDF in 144 DPI and I can't seem to find a way to increase the DPI.

Some code samples:

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <css>
      
      @page
      {
        size: 3.75in 2.25in;
        margin: 0;
      }

      html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .pdf-page {
        page-break-after: always;
      }

      .document-card {
        width: 3.5in;
        height: 2in;
      }

      .document-card-bleed {
        width: 3.75in;
        height: 2.25in;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }


    </css>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pdf-page">
      <div class="document-card-bleed">
        <div class="document-card front-bg">
          <%= html.html_safe %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ruby/Grover/Puppeteer config

```
    def grover_config
      {
        # debug: { headless: false, devtools: true },
        # clip: { x: 0, y: 0, width: "3.75in", height: "2.25in" },
        # viewport: { width: "3.75in", height: "2.25in" },
        # width: "3.75in",
        # height: "2.25in",
        prefer_css_page_size: true,
        margin: { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
        omit_background: false,
        print_background: true,
        launch_args: %w[--disable-web-security --no-sandbox],
        timeout: 2000,
        # wait_until: "domcontentloaded"
      }
    end
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1wKc.png)

The output is in the right printing size, however it's only 144 DPI.

Any clue would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this any use: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1057

Comment: @BenTrewern Sadly not. I had found that github issue during my research but I was still unsuccessful.

Comment: Do the DPI matter if it is just text and the one horizontal line? Text is scalable, so if you print that PDF with 300, 600 or even 1200 DPI, the text should be perfect, shouldn't it?